# Regex to replace last occurrence of a string in each line

Tags: regex, linux, shell, scripting, sed

I am using `sed -e 's/\(.*\)ABC/\1DEF/' myfile` to replace the last occurrence of `ABC` with `DEF` in a file.

I want to modify it to replace the last occurrence of `ABC` with `DEF` in **each line** in the file.

Is it possible to do with regex ?

Thanks

Comment: Actually `sed -e 's/\(.*\)ABC/\1DEF/' will replace last occurrence of `ABC` in each line of the file.

Comment: @anubhava is right. In fact, I am not sure you explained well what you are looking for.

Comment: @anubhava i though it just replaced last occurrence in the file, and not in each of the lines. i might be wrong. tested it with `/g` at the end like it was suggested and it worked as well.

Comment: On my Ubuntu linux and Mac having `/g` flag wasn't needed to replace last occurrence of `ABC`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add 'g' to the end of your sed:

```
sed -e 's/\(.*\)ABC/\1DEF/g'
```

This tells sed to replace every occurrence of your regex ("globally") instead of only the first occurrence.

**EDIT:** You should also add a `$`, if you want to ensure that it is replacing the last occurrence of ABC on the line:

```
sed -e 's/\(.*\)ABC$/\1DEF/g'
```

Comment: `$` will not guarantee only last occurrence of `ABC`, but will guarantee, that it is end of a row. So, it may be unnecessary.