# Using sed to replace last occurrence

Tags: linux, string, unix, sed

I got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271348/regex-to-replace-last-occurrence-of-a-string-in-each-line) question and other questions over the internet, but not able to solve the following scenario:

**The input string is :** `SF_db_gobfid01_20141209/SF_db_gobfid01_bat_20141209.lst`

**The output will be:** `SF_db_gobfid01_20141209/SF_db_gobfid01_bat_20150122.lst`

but the following are not working:

```
echo "SF_db_gobfid01_20141209/SF_db_gobfid01_bat_20141209.lst" | sed 's/20141209$/20150122/'
```

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: It's not working because `2041209$` does not match due to the end-of-line anchor. Your input contains stuff after `2041209`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Remove the end of the line anchor.
- Use capturing group.

  ```
  echo "SF_db_gobfid01_20141209/SF_db_gobfid01_bat_20141209.lst" | sed 's/\(.*\)20141209/\120150122/'
  ```

  `.*`   is greedy by default. It would match all the characters as much as possible. So that it captures all the characters upto the last number `20141209`. In basic sed, capturing groups are written as `\(..\)`, which are used to capture characters.

Comment: Its working but I have another problem. If want to use a veriable for those dates then what to use? Code like `echo "SF_db_gobfid01_20141209/SF_db_gobfid01_bat_20141209.lst" | sed 's/\(.*\)$FIRST_DATE/\1$LAST_DATE/'` is not working

Comment: put the sed code inside double quotes. `sed "s/\(.*\)$FIRST_DATE/\1$LAST_DATE/"`

Answer (score 0):

Use `/2` as an argument to the `s` command (see [this reference](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-8) for more details):

```
echo "SF_db_gobfid01_20141209/SF_db_gobfid01_bat_20141209.lst" | sed -r 's/20141209/20150122/2'
# prints "SF_db_gobfid01_20141209/SF_db_gobfid01_bat_20150122.lst"
```